# Windows Server Core 2016 having graphical issues

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016, windows-server-core, graphics

I am just experimenting with Windows Server Core on 2016 for the first time (running under VMWare ESXi 6.5) and I keep having graphical bugs every so often, if the screensaver comes up, when I move the mouse or press the keyboard, everything remains black until it is redrawn.

For example, with task manager open, if I press tab a few times, I see the following:

[image]

This is getting quite annoying and I was wondering if anyone has seen it before or if anyone can offer any advice?

A quick solution I have found is to press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>, then restore to original size in order for the entire screen to be redrawn, but, I would prefer to not have to do this.

p.s. the graphics card within ESX has been assigned 4MB - is that enough or should I increase? I have full install of Windows Desktop Experience that are using 4MB, so, I thought it should be ok.

Comment: This looks more like a VMRC bug than a bug in the graphics driver or a settings problem. Did you try replacing the VMRC by VMWare Workstation or the Workstation Player (both are capable of connecting to ESX(i) consoles)?

Comment: @the-wabbit - Thanks, interesting... I tried via the web viewer in addition to remote console... I'll try through workstation. Thanks.... I didn't think of that :(